# blocked with Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Tags: android, android-studio

Till yesterday everything was working fine.

I didnt update anything in between.

But all of sudden, i am keep getting this error "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt"

I tried updting sdk to 27.0.0, but still getting the same error message.

Tried deleting .gradle folder and build folder and cleaning project many times. But not help.

What went wrong here?

Here is my build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.udayrepo.doctortracker"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Just to add, Even i created a new project with above gradle settings, getting the same error message.

Answer (score 1):

The above error is really annoying without any clues where the problem is.

As many others said, i tried exploring replacing each of these libraries in my app.gradle file.

I search each of the latest packages in [Android SDK Plackage](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages) and updated each package in my gradle file with below

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

then it started working.

I am just sharing the solution as it may help others aswell. Just look for latest and update install required packages.